# nhibernate logs sql for postgres but not for sql server

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to nhibernate (but used hibernate for java before).

I built a session factory for our sql server database (sql server enterprise edition 8)

```
ISessionFactory factory2 = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(@"user id=xx; password=xxx;server=xxx;initial catalog=xxx")
    .ShowSql()
  )
  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
    .AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaValidator(cfg).Validate())
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

So I use the `ShowSql()` method to log the queries to the console.

In my programm I load / create two objects and want to persist them and then do a update on a column:

```
using (var session = sf.OpenSession())
{
    session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Always;
    using (var ta = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        PMA pm = session.CreateCriteria<PMA>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "HANSER")).List<PMA>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (pm == null)
        {
            pm = new PMA();
            pm.Prio = "1";
            pm.Name = "HANSER";
            pm.Datum = DateTime.Now;
            session.Save(pm);
        }

        Clip clip = new Clip();
        clip.PMA = pm;
        clip.sys_created = DateTime.Now;
        clip.sys_name = "system name";
        clip.Title = "Test";
        session.Save(clip);

        Console.ReadKey();

        clip.Title = "PETERSEN";
        session.SaveOrUpdate(clip);
        session.Transaction.Commit();
        session.Flush();
        session.Dispose();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The first insert for the pm object will be logged on the console, but the other insert and the update for the clip object don't appear in the console. When I look in the database, I see there is everything right, everything will be inserted and updated. But I want to see the query. I try to set flush mode to always and make a session.Flush() to the session at the end and then a session.Dispose(), but nothing changes.

When I use postgres (only change the sessionfactory), I see all query logs.
How can I let nhibernate log all queries for sql server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ADO.NET batching (on by default in SQL Server, which supports it), DML queries are not logged to the console.